# How to import data from ParAccel to HDFS

Tags: paraccel

ParAccel is Analytical database (PADB). We have huge amount of data to be imported from ParAccel (PADB) to HDFS. Appreciate if someone share if any work around to export the data from PADB

Comment: I am looking for options whether we can use Sqoop to extract the data from PADB.

Comment: And please note currently PADB is outside of Hadoop Cluster